# System.ExecutionEngine exception in visual studio 2012

Tags: windows-8

i am working on windows 8 release preview metro style xaml/C# apps, i am creating a player app, my app breaks and throws a

"unhandled System.ExecutionEngine exception occurred in Unknown module"  and does not produce a stack trace.

i dont know which part of the code does the app break and as the exception occurs in runtime

i am using Visual studio 2012 RC

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a breakpoint anywhere in your C# application (*before* the crash occurs - program start is fine).
2. Bring up "Call Stack window"
3. When the exception occurs, you should break.

   When you break, you can examine anything you want - including the call stack, and the code that invoked it.